# Using Wordpress Functions.php to insert JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to insert the flexslider.js and theme.js using functions.php. However, it doesn't load the flexslider.js and theme.js files when I view the source file.

I've downloaded the flex slider files and inserted jquery.flexslider-min.js as js/flexslider.js.

Functions.php

```
// Load the Theme JS
function theme_js() {

    wp_register_script( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/flexslider.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    if( is_page( 'home' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider' );
    }   
    wp_enqueue_script('theme_js',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );
```

Theme.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
});
```

Scripts from the source file

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
```

Comment: You can always override Wordpress' crap and just throw those script tags in your footer.php --

Comment: I agree with vanda. enqueue is good for avoiding duplications and conflicts in libraries, but it is not really necessary. You can just put the script tags in the footer yourself.

Comment: @rm-vanda is completely correct - don't add resource files via PHP, it's one overhead you don't want. Also, I would very much recommend you load Flexslider from a CDN as opposed to using one of your server.